# (CakePHP) Make rows of 3 using SQL data for products

Tags: javascript, css, sql, cakephp, rows

So I have been having trouble finding the right answer to getting each product here displaying in rows of 3. They are now currently only in vertical.

This is how this part was made via `Products.shoe_home` (a view)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">
      <?php 
         foreach ($products as $product): ?>
             <h2><?php echo h($product['Product']['p_name']); ?>&nbsp;</h2>
             <p><?php echo h($product['Product']['p_description']);?>&nbsp; </p>
             <div style ="padding-right: 5em">
             <?php
                if (isset($product['Product']['p_image'])) {
                   echo $this->Html->image($product['Product']['p_image']);
                } else {
                   echo "No Image Available";
                }
             ?>
             </div>
             &nbsp;
             <p>
                SHOE SIZE:  <?php echo h($product['Product']['p_size']); ?>
                &nbsp;
             </p>    
             <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View Details >>'),
                                              array(
                                                 'controller' => '/shoepages/',
                                                 'action' => 'shoe_view',
                                                 $product['Product']['id']),
                                                 array('class' => 'btn'));
              ?>                        
         <?php endforeach; ?>
      &nbsp;                   
      </div><!--/span-->   
    </div><!--/row-->
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I seem to be not allowed to post an image at the moment, so I apologise in advance. Any ideas would be appreciated. The data works on my end.

Comment: What happens if you move `<div class="span4">` inside foreach loop? Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, it's bootstrap 2. Thanks for that suggestion. and well I did that. I guess it does do it in a row of 3, but then the image shrinks and the text all jumbles up together. So it's nearly there, but is there a way to allow the text and image to get enough space to be big enough

Comment: Create a fiddle with your rendered html and css. It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: No, no, no Sorry. I made an accidental mistake. I had another Span4 somewhere. Thanks a bunch. Looks great.